# can Mathematica be instructed to print-to-file smaller pdf files?

Tags: printing, pdf-generation, wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica 9.0.1.0, Linux.

Create a notebook cell with only the word "Section" and apply the format "Section" to it.  Then create a variable x and evaluate it.  Then print the two-cell notebook to a pdf file.  (We often have to pass these forth and back via email to mobile users.)  The resulting pdf file is just under 1MB big.  A few more modest additions, and Mma print-to-file yields a 2-3MB files from about one page of notebook.  for comparison, my 800 page dense latex-generated book with R graphics consumes about 4MB.

can Mma be instructed to produce more compact pdf files?  I know it can rasterize graphics, but this isn't really a graphics problem.

Comment: Google shrink pdf file to find lots of people talking about utilities that sometimes dramatically reduce the size of pdf files

Comment: see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file

Comment: when you say 'print to file', what driver?  Acrobat wont produce such large files even if you raster the whole page.

Comment: it's not the other stackexchange question.  that one was about graphics.  I have no graphics.  I basically have an almost empty text file here.  by "print to file", I just use the built-in Mma menu option on linux.  I choose no rasterization etc.

Answer (score 1):

this comes from the folks from wolfram support:

The pdf files are large because they contain embedded fonts for faithful reproduction.

One way to reduce the file size would be to set certain options below to False.
   This can be done from Mathematica menu by going to Format->Options Inspector->
   Select 'Global Preferences' from Show option values-> go to
      Notebook Options->Printing Options-> EmbedExternalFonts set to False.
   Do the same for Notebook Options->Printing Options->EmbedStandardPostScriptFonts
    set to False.

However, the PDF that is generated may not look exactly like you want it, especially if you send it to someone else. However, if you just want to keep the PDF on your machine, where the fonts exist anyway, this may be a good default option.

apparently, their developers are working on the problem, too.